# Freebase Related Models

Tags: dataset

It may be unlikely that anyone knows this but I have a specific question about Freebase.  Here is the Freebase page from the [Ford Taurus automotive model](http://www.freebase.com/m/014_d3) .  It has a property called "Related Models".  Does anyone know how this list of related models was compiled.  What is the similarity measure that they use?  I don't think it is only about other wikipedia pages that link to or from this page.  Alternatively, it may be that this is user generated.  Does anyone know for sure?